# string manipulation with awk/sed and cut together

Tags: bash, sed, awk, cut

I'm trying to manipulate the following strings:

```
/var/www/vhosts/www.xxx.nl/HTML/wp-includes/version.php:$wp_version = '3.5';    
/var/www/vhosts/www.yyy.nl/HTML/wp-includes/version.php:$wp_version = '2.9';
/var/www/vhosts/www.zzz.nl/HTML/wp-includes/version.php:$wp_version = '3.2.1';
```

to produce the output:

```
www.xxx.nl 3.5
www.yyy.nl 2.9
www.zzz.nl 3.2.1
```

With cut I can show column 1:

```
cut -d '/' -f5
```

and with awk and sed I can show column 2:

```
awk '{print $3}' | sed -e 's/^.//' -e 's/..$//'
```

but how to combine these commands so that it shows the intended output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can make it:

```
$ awk -F"[/']" '{print $5, $9}' file
www.xxx.nl 3.5
www.yyy.nl 2.9
www.zzz.nl 3.2.1
```

What we do with `-F"[/']"` is to define two possible field delimiters: `/` or `'`. Then it is a matter of checking the position of the desired fields, which happens to be 5th and 9th.

Comment: that's it! Thanks for the explanation defining multiple field delimiters.